# How to concretely display any kind of content within a drupal module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

this will be my first question on the site, I hope I'll be clear!

So I'm working on adapting a regular php/html/js website to a drupal site. There are some specific things a can't do with the available modules, so a need to create some. I've been wandering a lot on the web, watch and read some tutorials but I dont get exactly how to display simple html/js/php with a block module for instance.

For example, I want to display this in a block module :

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script> 
<div class="myDiv"></div> 
<script> 
$(".maparea").append('<p class='myText'>Hello there!</p>'); 
</script>`
```

On the other hand I have my block_view function:

```
`function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    $block['subject'] = 'my Module title';
    $block['content'] = 'some content';
    return $block;
}`
```

If i replace that 'some content' with my raw code, well first I don't think it is the best way, a overall it doesn't work so well. Besides, I would like to use the drupal API to insert js (drupal_add_js), but how?

```
`block['content'] .= drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module').'/myScript.js');`
```

Finally, I found some information about theme system, and templates. So it seems I have to implement my_module_template.tpl.php, and implement hook_theme in my_module.module.

It's pretty blurry, so I really need some help to understand the basics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you know Drupal, to create a block, you should use hook_block_info() 
`function module_name_block_info() {
  $blocks['block_name'] = array(
    'info' => t('The text you want to display'),
    'region' => 'Region you want the block',
  );
  return $blocks;
}` 
If after this you want to alter that block, you can do it from hook_block_info_alter(). More details you can get from Drupal Block Api

Comment: About the drupal_add_js(), you can't just use it like that, if you read the description from the drupal site, you can see what that function returns, and i don't think is what you want. You can add a js, file, either with drupal_add_js(), either with dependencies in .info from a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_css()` in a `hook_preprocess_block__module()` or `hook_preprocess_block__module__delta()` function (replacing 'hook', 'module' and 'delta' with specific values) that you define in your module alongside your `hook_block_view()` function, or in your theme's 'template.php' file.